# Leaving edit mode loses almost all detail

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm fairly new to Blender (and 3D modelling). I'm trying to model a human ear to attach to a head I've made. This is my second attempt because I wasn't happy with the first. I started with a single plain and extruded the basic shape. I added a subsurf modifier with subdivisions set to 1 and applied it. Then I added another subsurf modifer (which I haven't applied yet) and currently have the subdivisions set to 2. But I've just noticed that when I switch to object mode the ear loses almost all detail and I can't figure out why. This didn't happen on my first attempt at making an ear but I can't think of anything I've done differently other than laying out the initial faces in a slightly different pattern.

**Edit Mode:**

[image: Edit Mode]

**Object Mode:**

[image: Object Mode]

**EDIT:**

**Subdivisions set to 0:**

[image: 0 Subdivisions]

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have a shapekey?

Comment: If you set View to 0, does it look right again?

Comment: Can you tell me how to check if I have a shapekey please? I haven't used them before, so I assume the answer is no, but won't hurt to check.

I've added a picture with the view set to 0. I think the normal's were facing the wrong way in the original pics, hence the colour difference.

Comment: I found the shape keys and no I don't have any.

Comment: Here is the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4046/

Comment: The Scale units in your file are set to 0.01, and additionally you scaled the object to 0.0003 (or more zeros, a lot anyway) in Object mode. Apply scale and it should return back to normal. It's hard to explain that behaviour though as it isn't due to Subsurf

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: Applying the scale worked, thank you. I'm trying to create a model for Unreal Engine 4 and I saw a tutorial which said to set the units to the Centimetres preset (which is 0.01). I don't ever remember scaling the object, only selected verts so I don't know how that's happened but thank you.